# sliding panel for website pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks for viewing my question, I will try to explain as good as possible what I need.

This is my site http://hoveralls.design-way.ro/ - I want to make all pages to slide down pretty much like here http://example.design-way.ro/ - to make this work I used Hoveralls Jquery plugin which you can find on code canyon.

Well... I have 2 problems:

1. First and the most important is that Parallax plugin that I used for the animation in the middle works with jQuery 1.2.6 and Hoveralls with 1.7.1. If I change the jQuery version animation stops working and hoveralls does not work on 1.2.6
2. In the example I gave before you can see that the pages slide down but I need them to close when another page is open.

Before I posted I searched for an answer and I found this [jsfiddle.net/fE8ks/26/](http://jsfiddle.net/fE8ks/26/). I think this would work if I can somehow close all divs when HOME button is clicked and the default state will be hidden.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to do this with plain old javascript(no jQuery)? I will need to controll the height and a text speed effect will be nice.
2. Will my website load slowly since this is basically one page?Pages will be mostly simple, I will only use JS for some tabs and for the gallery.

I emailed the developer of hoveralls asking for some help and he gave me this code:

```
// 1. HTML
   a div with id "portfolio_slider"

// GIVE YOUR PORTFOLIO BUTTON AN ID
<a id="porfolio_button">Slide Open Portfolio</a>

// 2. CSS
#portfolio_slider {
     display:none;
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:auto; // may need to play with this 
     border-bottom:3px solid #CCC;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     z-index:99999;
}


// 3. JAVASCRIPT :) 
A. Make sure you load jQuery library
B. Place this after the jQuery library (at the end of the head tag on your index.html)

<script type="text/javascript">
     // WAIT UNTIL ALL IMAGES ARE LOADED (BETTER THAN DOCUMENT.READY)
    $(window).load({   


         // BINDS THE CLICK EVENT TO YOUR PORTFOLIO BUTTON
        $('#portfolio_button').bind('click',function(e){   

                 // GET THE CURRENT CSS TOP POSITION OF THE PANEL AS AN NUMBER
                 var SliderPos=parseInt( $('#portfolio_slider').css('top'),10);      

                // IF THE PANEL IS OPEN (DOWN)
               if ( SliderPos > 0 ){

                       // ANIMATE THE PORTFOLIO SLIDER PANEL DOWN USING THE CSS TOP PROPERTY
                       // NOTE: IF YOU HAVE JQUERY UI OR THE EASING PLUGIN, YOU CAN CHANGE SWING 
                       $('#portfolio_slider').animate({'top' : '0px'},{duration:500,queue:false,specialeasing:{ 'top' :  'swing' }});


              // IF THE PANEL IS CLOSED (UP)
               }else{

                       // ANIMATE THE PORTFOLIO SLIDER PANEL DOWN USING THE CSS TOP PROPERTY
                       // NOTE: THE TOP POSITION WILL BE EQUAL TO THE HEIGHT OF #PORTFOLIO SLIDER
                       $('#portfolio_slider').animate({'top' : '500px'},{duration:500,queue:false,specialeasing:{ 'top' :  'swing' }});
               };         


       // PREVENTS DEFAULT BEHAVIOR OF BROWSER NAVIGATING TO THE LINK
        e.preventDefault();  
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


// ALTERNATIVELY
jQuery makes this stuff easy. Instead of the JS section above, you can alternatively use the following (less control over the animation)
<script type="text/javascript">

     // WAIT UNTIL ALL IMAGES ARE LOADED (BETTER THAN DOCUMENT.READY)
    $(window).load({   
         // BINDS THE CLICK EVENT TO YOUR PORTFOLIO BUTTON
        $('#portfolio_button').bind('click',function(e){   
            // SLIDE TOGGLE THE DIV
             $('#portfolio_slider').slideToggle(500);           
       // PREVENTS DEFAULT BEHAVIOR OF BROWSER NAVIGATING TO THE LINK
        e.preventDefault();  
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

however it does not seem to work.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `<a id="porfolio_button">Slide Open Portfolio</a>` -- should the ID there be `"portfolio_button"`?

Comment: you're right but is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but be sure to change the reference to the jquery.js file to fit your needs ... Maybe use Google cdn:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #portfolio_slider {
         display:none;
         position:absolute;
         width:100%;
         height:auto; // may need to play with this 
         border-bottom:3px solid #CCC;
         top:0px;
         left:0px;
         z-index:99999;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="portfolio_slider"></div>
<a id="portfolio_button">Slide Open Portfolio</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // WAIT UNTIL ALL IMAGES ARE LOADED (BETTER THAN DOCUMENT.READY)
    $(function(){   
        // BINDS THE CLICK EVENT TO YOUR PORTFOLIO BUTTON
        $('#portfolio_button').bind('click',function(e){   
            // SLIDE TOGGLE THE DIV
             $('#portfolio_slider').toggle('slideUp');           
            // PREVENTS DEFAULT BEHAVIOR OF BROWSER NAVIGATING TO THE LINK
            e.preventDefault();  
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```